# Build PowerPoint document with SharePoint List data

Tags: 2007

I was wondering if anyone has a solution for importing SharePoint list data into a PowerPoint document. For instance, if I create a document library and set the default document type to "Word document", [I can use "Quick Parts" to link the template](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=46) to SharePoint list fields.

I'd like to use a similar technique for PowerPoint.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but unfortunately I received an error. > Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set I have an .pptm added to an SharePoint List item. The list consist out of Title and Test (Single line of text). In my pptm I have following command: ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.ContentTypeProperties("Test").Value If I do it with an hard coded text, it works fine ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test" What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to save the presentation as a Macro-Enabled Presentation (.pptm) and then save it to your SharePoint list.  Once there, add code along the lines below to whatever event/button fits your needs

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.ContentTypeProperties("MyCustom").Value
```

This will update the text of the first element on the first slide (usually the presentation title) and set it to the value of the field "MyCustom" that is from the SharePoint list.

It will take some playing around to get it working but you should be able to get there.